# Django raw query fails with ILIKE?

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

I have been going crazy trying to solve this. Any direction is appreciated .

I have the following sql query :

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM hotel_hotel h WHERE name ILIKE '%raffles%'"
```

I am trying to do :

```
Hotel.objects.raw(sql)
```

The % in `"%raffles%"` here is causing problems here. I am getting this error :

```
  TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

This doesn't happen when I do a `ILIKE 'raffles'`. Any workarounds for this ?

Comment: Possibly use double %.

Comment: +1 to double %. '%' are interpreted as parameter, so you need to escape them.